# asp.net mvc 4 dropdown list with model isn't working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, dropdownlistfor

I'm converting an asp.net forms site to MVC and am having an issue with a dropdown list.

*Model extract:*
    namespace adminLte.Models
//then further down

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Player Segment Required")]  
[Display(Name = "Player Segment")]  
public string Segment { get; set; }  
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> PlayerSegmentList { get; set; }
```

//model class List

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getPlayerSegmentList()  
{  
  List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();  
  var data = new[]{  
   new SelectListItem{ Value="&amp;Segment=1000",Text="1,000+"},  
   new SelectListItem{ Value="&amp;Segment=750-999",Text="750-999"},  
   new SelectListItem{ Value="&amp;Segment=500-749",Text="500-749"},  
   new SelectListItem{ Value="&amp;Segment=400-499",Text="400-499"}
  };
  myList = data.ToList();
  return myList;
}
```

*controller:*
//?? not sure about this...

```
playerExtract objModel = new playerExtract();
objModel.PlayerSegmentList = objModel.getPlayerSegmentList();
ViewBag.pSeg = new SelectList(objModel, "SegmentID", "Segment"); 

*HTML form*  
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Segment, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-2" })  
@Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Segment, ViewBag.pSeg as SelectList  , new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Segment", @class = "form-control" } })  
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Segment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

//Results
*compile error*

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Segment'.
```

I'm new to MVC and am missing something - Any assistance provided is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Model.PlayerSegmentList` as your source collection used to build the select options. So pass that as the second parameter of your `Html.DropDownListFor` method call.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Segment, Model.PlayerSegmentList,
                 new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Segment", @class = "form-control" } })
```

Also in your controller code, this line does not make any sense!

```
ViewBag.pSeg = new SelectList(objModel, "SegmentID", "Segment");
```

The first parameter of the `SelectList` has to be a collection, not your class object! That should give you a compile time error!. Just remove that line since you already have the data you needed in your `PlayerSegmentList` property

So your cleaned up controller code would be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm = new YourVieWModel();
  var objModel = new playerExtract();
  vm.PlayerSegmentList = objModel.getPlayerSegmentList();
  return View(vm); 
}
```

That should work assuming you are view is strongly typed tot he same `YourViewModel`

I would also recommend using **P**ascal**C**asing for C# class names/method names :)